# Cannot deploy custom artifact to elasticbeanstalk and bypass git archiving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I am trying to deploy a custom zip file, to elastic beanstalk. I have followed the guidelines [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact) but after running

```
eb deploy -v --debug
```

to get verbose output, I still can see using the zip produced from git archiving instead of my zip
The artifact path in config.yml is absolute.

```
2018-04-19 10:23:52,476 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'ApplicationVersions': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'date': 'Thu, 19 Apr 2018 07:23:52 GMT', 'RequestId': '5d6d7dad-1a8c-48b0-9470-129cd39c2f09', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}}
```

2018-04-19 10:23:52,477 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /home/ppe/git_src/ice

Creating application version archive "app-2_0_4-15-gb03f-180419_102352".
2018-04-19 10:23:52,478 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /home/ppe/git_src/ice
2018-04-19 10:23:52,478 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /home/ppe/git_src/ice

INFO: creating zip using git archive HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was nesting...I have accidentally put the option nested under global and thus it was failing